# Why JS not working sometimes in AppleWebkit?

Tags: javascript, django, webkit

I have deployed a django project recently and everything is working fine but one issue is giving me real headache..

I have validation code in js in login/register page. sometimes, validation code doesnot work properly and goes to backend and i will get error message saying that

```
IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key"
```

But I really check username being entered in registration form if it already exists in db. only if not, then i will let the user register. the same also for email.

why this doesnot work in iphone,ipad,mac... ?

here is the page, you can see the js source code

http://wohne-wo-du-willst.de/anmelden/?next=/

Comment: First, I get ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $ on that page.

Comment: Second, I don't get any error like that on Safari on Mac. You fixed it already?

Comment: @sul4bh, no, i didnot fix the problem,